# Secure dnsmasq dns daemon with whitelist

Tags: linux, dns, dnsmasq

I'm using dnsmasq on a server (bound to wan IP) and would like to add an acl/whitelist for ip ranges/ip address allowed to resolve dns using my server.

I can't seem to find anything from Google, is there an option to whitelist/block non allowed addresses from resolving using my server?

Please don't suggest using iptables or other firewall solutions.

Comment: *iptables* is the only solution.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae that would explain lack of any option in the docs/www. Guess I'll just use iptables then. Thanks (if you want, feel free to post this as an answer

Comment: Done, glad to see you accepted iptables as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I know is through *iptables*.

It is easiest to do this with [ipset](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ipset): create a list of allowed IPs,

```
    ipset create good_ips hash:net
```

add your ips to the list,

```
     ipset add good_ips 8.8.8.8
     ipset add good_ips 192.168.155.0/24
```

Then you can block all IPs **not** in the list, trying to access your DNS server, as follows:

```
      iptables -A INPUT -p udp  --dport 53 -m set  --match-set !  good_ips src -j DROP
```

This can be made permanent with:

```
      ipset save > /etc/ipset.conf
      systemctl enable ipset
```

(the last command is for *systemd* services, which is by now most of Linuxes; if you are not on such a system, please adjust it accordingly).

Comment: I get `iptables v1.4.21: Set ! doesn't exist.` when I try to run that iptables command

Comment: don't you need a rule to ACCEPT the ips in the whitelist?

Comment: @chovy It depends on your default policy: if your default policy is DROP, then yes, you do. But if your default policy is ACCEPT, then you do not.

Comment: can you give a more complete example? I am unable to get this to work, and you have a syntax error as well. (see first comment) -- maybe you can comment here: http://serverfault.com/questions/759927/how-to-setup-a-whitelist-using-iptables-and-ipset